# check for any column contains provided values after group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set like this.

```
CREATE TABLE EntityItems (
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    EnitityItemId INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id, EnitityItemId)
);

INSERT INTO EntityItems
  VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(3, 4)
;
```

I want to filter this table where any of the group contains both 1 and 2 values(in EntityItemId column) after grouping by Id column.

let's say I am checking for both 1 and 2 values to be there in a group. I am expecting the result as

```
Id
1
2
```

Please let me know if you need clarification.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can aggregate and check, if the distinct count of entity item IDs is equal to 2 in a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT id
       FROM elbat
       WHERE enitityitemid IN (1, 2)
       GROUP BY id
       HAVING count(DISTINCT enitityitemid) = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try a query like below

```
select Id
from
yourtable where
EnitityitemId  in (1,2)-- this is your condition
group by Id
having
count(1)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach to filtering groups based on multiple values is to use self-joins and apply the condition for each value on each of the twin tables. With 2 distinct values, you can use a single join:

```
SELECT ei0.Id
  FROM EntityItems AS ei0
    JOIN EntityItems AS ei1 ON ei0.id = ei1.id
  WHERE ei0.EntityitemId = 1
    AND ei1.EntityitemId = 2
;
```

Depending on the exact nature of conditions, the query may need a `GROUP BY` clause on the selected columns, though it's unnecessary for the sample case.

For the sample, this query performs well given the appropriate indices. The [query plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359705/90527) with the sample data:

[image: Query plan for join-based multi value group condition]

With a larger table, I'd expect the index seek to have a smaller impact and the scan to dominate. Compare with the execution plan for the group-and-count approach from [sticky bit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376537/90527), which also has a single scan:

[image: Query plan for group-and-count multi value group condition]

The group-and-count can more succinctly be adapted to work with additional values (add them to the `IN` list and change the count used in the `COUNT` comparison); the join-based approach will require an additional join for each value. Also, if there isn't an appropriate index (or the condition precludes using and index), the performance of the join-based approach will be worse than the group-and-count. On the other hand, the join-based approach is possibly more readily adapted to some complex conditions.